# General question about Self-adjoint operators on Hilbert Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

so if I have a self-adjoint operator $K \in B(H,H)$. Then I found a theorem that said that

$A$ is invertible if and only if $(A^*Ax,x) \geq c||x||$ and $(AA^*x,x) \geq c||x||$ for all $x$.

Then does that mean that if I have a self adjoint operator like $K$.
$(K^*Kx,x) = (Kx,Kx) \geq 0$, but then as long $Kx \not = 0$ for all $x$ i.e. $K = 0$, then $K$ is invertible because I have $(Kx,Kx)> 0$. But that is weird to me because that means every self-adjoing bounded linear operator is invertible.

Comment: $(Kx, Kx) > 0$ is not the same thing as $(Kx,Kx) \geq c \|x\|$. The constant $c$ is not allowed to depend on $x$.

Comment: Furthermore, $Kx\ne 0$ for all $x$ does not hold for every bounded self-adjoint. Take, for example, an orthogonal projection to a proper subspace.

Comment: Looking at the example below it seems that for the finite case that $(Kx,Kx)>0$ is the same as $(Kx,Kx) \geq c||x||$, is that true?

Comment: For finite dimensional spaces it is the same, as the unit sphere is compact and you can set $c=\min_{\|x\|=1}(Kx,Kx)=(Kx_0,Kx_0)>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an infinite-dimensional vector space, there's a big difference between $(Ax,Ax)\geq c\|x\|^{2}$ for all $x\in H$ and $(Ax,Ax)>0$ for all nonzero $x\in H$. For an example, consider $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$. Then if $A(e_{i})=2^{-i}e_{i}$ for all $i\geq 0,$ we can see that the inverse must be $A^{-1}(e_{i})=2^{i}e_{i}$, but this is not a bounded linear operator.

We see that $(Ax,Ax)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^{-2i}x_{i}^{2}>0$ whenever $x\neq0$, but for any $c>0,$ if $x\in\mathrm{span}(\{e_{i}\}_{i\geq I}),$ where $I$ is large enough that $2^{-2I}<c$, then $(Ax,Ax)\leq 2^{-2I}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x_{i}^{2}<c\|x\|^{2}$. Therefore there is no $c>0$ for which this bound holds.

EDIT: Consider the optimization problem $$\min_{x\neq0}\frac{(Ax,Ax)}{\|x\|^{2}},$$ which is equivalent to $$\min_{\|x\|=1}(Ax,Ax).$$ The unit sphere $\{x\in H:\|x\|=1\}$ is compact if and only if $H$ is finite-dimensional, so in this case, there is some $x$ which achieves this minimum $c$, which gives $(Ax,Ax)\geq c\|x\|^{2}$ for all $x\in H$. When this minimization is not over a compact set, there is no such guarantee (just consider the example I gave above).

Comment: But if I am limited to finite dimensional vector spaces. Say something like $\mathbb{R^4}$. Then we do have $(Ax,Ax)>0$ implies $(Ax,Ax)> c ||x||$ ? Because the series is finite and thus it cannot converge to zero, correct?

Comment: @Kori In finite dimension $Ax \neq 0$ implies that $A$ is injective and therefore surjective, hence invertible.

Comment: I've added an edit giving another way of thinking about this.